# how to deny user to access sub folders and file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

on local machine ,i created sample project on mvc4 (razor) and create directory named "x" and put a text file "a.txt" in it.

```
http://localhost:64471/x/a.txt
```

in my web config i deny all user to access to "x" folder by this config:

```
<location path="x">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Now if user send this request :

```
http://localhost:64471/x/
```

it works and return user to URL that defined in forms tag in web config.

but when user send this request :

```
http://localhost:64471/x/a.txt
```

can read text file in browser(browser shows contents of text file).

i want to know how to deny user to access all files and subfolders in "x" folder?

Comment: Theoretically, `path="x"` should restrict everything under x folder. What kind of authentication do you use? *For example, Form authentication* In addition, where do you keep that `location` tag - application's root web.config or web.config inside x folder?

Comment: @Win i use form authentication.i put location in root under <configuration> tag

Comment: omit location to include all files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested with `path="x"` in root web.config. It restrict everything under x folder; it won't even let me browse ~/x. I get redirected to login page.

Could you try full path to a.txt like this in root web.config?

```
<location path="x/a.txt">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

If it still doesn't work, you can try creating a web.config inside x folder with the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="a.txt">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but if you are having issues and dealing with text or html files, you might want to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37080857/9266) stackoverflow question.

In short, you might need to add this to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
        <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"  />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

As [kirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/935779/kirk) points out, files such as .txt and .html files are handled by IIS and not ASP.NET, so the authorization rules aren't applied to them.