# Restrict access to the Logs folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ASP.NET MVC Application`, which has a `Logs` folder, where the log files are stored. Normally, I would access it as `localhost/Logs/Log.common.txt` and see the logs. However, now I want to restrict it.

Now I have Logs controller, which has an Authorize attribute set to the `Admin` only:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
  [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
  public class LogsController : BaseController
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    LogFile logFile = GetLogFileByName("log.Common.txt");
    return View(logFile);
    }
  }
}
```

So now, if I try to go to `localhost/Logs`, then I get an unauthorized access error, however, if I go directly to `localhost/Logs/Log.common.txt` I still can see the file. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: You could simply not store the log files within your application's file structure. That would prevent it from getting served out. Longer term - you sure you want to deal with text files? That's hard to work with. Have you considered using a logging library like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/), and then combining that with an application logging framework like [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) or [Retrace](https://stackify.com/retrace/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IIS7+ add following web.config file into /Logs

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="Admin" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Earlier versions have [slightly different syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036629/how-to-deny-user-to-access-sub-folders-and-file).

Alternatively, move /logs into [/app_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528858/what-is-the-app-data-folder-used-for-in-visual-studio)